# How to specify 2 Wheres in Generic Class definition

Tags: c#, generics

```
public class GenericBuildService<T, T2> where T : IList<T2>
```

I need to also make sure any incoming T2 has implemented INode.

Not sure how to specify that when I already have a where in here for the IList.

UPDATE:

I just want to add more clarification on what my goal is here.  I need this service class to require an IList and also require a rootNode of myCustomType because I need to be able to work with both in various methods inside this class for various reasons...so I try to send those instances in like this but obviously I haven't constructed my class definition just right yet as it's not liking my usage of this class:

```
Node<FieldDependency> rootNode = new Node<FieldDependency>(_rootNode);
            var builder = new GenericBuildService<IList<FieldDependency>, FieldDependency>(_dependencies, rootNode);
```

so I'm trying to send in an IList<_dependencies> which is just a list of FieldDependency instances and also trying to send in a rootNode which is type Node

so not quite sure if I'm forming my class definition just right for the build service class, anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use type parameters *inside* generic types in your methods and properties. For example, if you have a method that accepts an `IList<T>` where `T` is your type parameter, you can simply do:

```
public class GenericBuildService<T>
    where T : INode
{
    GenericBuildService(IList<T> dependencies, T rootNode);
}
```

Then if `T` is, for example, `MyNode`, IntelliSense will show (and the compiler will verify) that only things that implement `IList<MyNode>` are passed to your constructor (or other members that use `T`):

```
GenericBuildService(IList<MyNode> dependencies, MyNode rootNode);
```

---

To specify multiple [*where* constraints](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5x73970.aspx) for different type parameters, you can repeat the `where` keyword:

```
public class GenericBuildService<T, T2>
    where T : INode
    where TList : IList<T>
{
    GenericBuildService(TList dependencies, T rootNode);
}
```

This means that *all* uses of `TList` are replaced by whatever type the user specifies, but this type *must* implement `IList<T2>`. For example, if `TList` is `ReadOnlyCollection<MyNode>` then IntelliSense will show (and the compiler will verify) that only `ReadOnlyCollection<MyNode>` objects are passed to your constructor:

```
GenericBuildService(ReadOnlyCollection<MyNode> dependencies, MyNode rootNode);
```

---

To specify multiple constraints on a single type parameter, separate them by comma's. Specify special constraints (`struct`, `class`) first, class constraints before interfaces, and `new()` last.

```
public class GenericBuildService<T, T2>
    where T : class, IList<T2>, new()
{
}
```

You can use type parameters in the constraints recursively.

The constraints specify what the type must be or implement. Their meaning:

- `class`: Only reference types are allowed. Reference types can be `null`.
- `struct`: Only non-nullable value types are allowed. Such value types cannot be `null`.
- Class constraint: The type *must* extend the specified type.
- Interface constraints: The type *must* implement *all* interfaces that are specified.
- `new()`: The type must have a parameterless constructor. All value types have such a constructor, but reference types may or may not have it.

You cannot use `class` *and* `struct` at the same time. To specify that you want to allow reference types and all value types, just don't specify `class` or `struct` at all.

---

If you don't have any type constraints for a generic type parameter, then you don't need to add a `where`.

```
public class MyClass<T>
{
}
```

Comment: thanks, I still don't understand why I'm having to do T: IList<T2> though to get this thing "happy"

Comment: @CoffeeAddict You don't need `T: IList<T2>` to keep the compiler happy. Instead, you can replace `T` in your code by `IList<T2>` directly and remove `T` altogether. I updated my post.

Answer (score 0):

You can specify multiple [where](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384067.aspx) constraints, one for each type parameter:

```
public class GenericBuildService<T, T2>
    where T : IList<T2>
    where T2 : INode
{
}
```